# Outlook Messenger conflicts with Virtualbox

Tags: outlook, virtualbox, conflict

The office I work in, uses Outlook Messenger for internal communication. And I want to use VirtualBox for some development purpose being in the office network.

But after installing VirtualBox the Outlook IP is somehow intercepted. I know, if I uninstall VBox, Outlook will function like before. But I don't want to uninstall VBox.

How can I resolve the conflict?

Is there a way I can temporarily shut off the VBox's IP configuration so the Outlook can work nice? In this way I can sacrifice Outlook for team communication for that niche bit of time while I would use VBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. Solution given by my colleage Mr. Afzal Hossain:

As of Windows 7:

**Step 1:** Open Network and Sharing Center:
[image: Open Network and Sharing Center]

**Step 2:** Change adapter settings:
[image: Change adapter settings]

**Step 3:** Disable the VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
[image: Disable the VirtualBox Host-Only Network]

And *yala!* Now get back to the Outlook Messenger and right click and Refresh the users, it'll work fine. :)

#### Bonus Tip

[image: Make a shortcut of VBox connection]
You can make it a Desktop Shortcut, so that you can easily Enable/Disable the connection anytime.

Props: Mr. Afzal Hossain Noman.